# constructor vs. onNavigatedTo

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

I am confused what I should do in constructor and what else should I do in a `onNavigatedTo` method in a Windows Phone page.

Particularly, where should I read storage and settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onNavigatedTo` is performed all the time when you navigate to this page, i.e. after navigation back from another page or deactivation application.

Page constructor is performed only once BEFORE page is loaded (after tombstoning it also needs to be loaded again)

Comment: If you construct page from file data - yes. In some situations I put `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method to page constructor to execute something in first frame draw (to draw UI first and then perform hard work on UI)